# « Livrée » ou « couleurs » avec le train etc. ?

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, synonymes, formulation, fréquence-utilisation

> *The cars have been painted in the new company livery.* / Les voitures ont été peintes aux nouvelles couleurs de la maison. (exemple de [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/livery/592600) pour un sens référant à une société).

En ce qui concerne une locomotive ou les wagons d'un train, l'emploi de [*livrée*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/livr%C3%A9e) est-il plus fréquent et usuel que celui de *(aux) couleurs (de)* ; s'agit-il de synonymes ; pense-t-on à première vue dans un contexte de traduction de [*livery*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/livery) comme dans l'exemple de Larousse qu'il y a équivalence avec la *livrée* ; je veux parler de représenter un drapeau sur un train, puis-je le faire avec *livrée* ?

Comment: Livrée est un plutôt un terme technique utilisé par les gens du métier et les amateur de trains. Le grand public ne connait pas vraiment ce mot.

Answer (score 2):

Le terme « livrée » dans le langage SNCF a un sens technique  qui est plutôt associé à un modèle standard qu'à une distinction particulière et/ou temporaire. Cet [article de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livr%C3%A9es_SNCF) fait l'historique des différentes livrées du matériel roulant SNCF.

**Exemples d'emplois :**

[Votez pour choisir la livrée des nouvelles rames TET !](https://www.ecologie.gouv.fr/votez-choisir-livree-des-nouvelles-rames-tet)

[Une livrée historique pour une rame historique. De plus la livrée actuelle des TGV est triste, sombre et je ne n’aime pas du tout comme la majorité des Français.](https://www.lettreducheminot.fr/materiel/retour-sur-le-referendum-faut-il-repeindre-en-orange-la-rame-tgv-du-premier-record/)

Il s'agit bien ici de décoration extérieure qui touche l'ensemble du matériel circulant sur les lignes.

Quand les rames arborent un signe dénotant une appartenance particulière (régionale, publicitaire, ...) on emploie plutôt « couleurs ». Dans le même [article de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livr%C3%A9es_SNCF) référencé en ouverture de cette réponse on peut lire :

> ...  la personnalisation du matériel TER aux couleurs des conseils régionaux qui les financent.

**Exemples d'emploi :**

[Présentation de la rame aux couleurs de la Basse-Normandie](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/normandie/2013/12/18/nouvelle-generation-de-train-entre-granville-et-paris-380037.html)

[De nouvelles rames aux couleurs de l’Occitanie pour le réseau TER](https://www.lejournaltoulousain.fr/societe/nouvelles-rames-ter-occitanie-81939/)

[Un train aux couleurs de l'Impressionnisme](https://www.detoursenfrance.fr/destinations/circuits/paris-normandie-un-train-sur-les-traces-des-impressionnistes-2996)

[Un train aux couleurs de la Schtroumpf Expérience](https://www.schtroumpfexperience.com/un-train-aux-couleurs-de-la-schtroumpf-experience/)

[Un Thalys aux couleurs de la Belgique](https://www.7sur7.be/home/un-thalys-aux-couleurs-de-la-belgique%7Ea43ad463/)

[“dans les Hauts-de-France, le seul renouvellement du pelliculage des TER coûte 30.000 euros par train, soit 10 millions d’euros au total”. Une somme importante pour simplement redécorer les rames aux couleurs de la nouvelle région...](https://www.capital.fr/economie-politique/reforme-des-regions-la-cour-des-comptes-redoute-dimportants-surcouts-1249178)

Ceci s'applique aussi au réseau Transilien et au métro :

[Les trains de la ligne C aux couleurs de Versailles](https://www.sortiraparis.com/album-photo/48574-les-trains-de-la-ligne-c-aux-couleurs-de-versailles)

[Sur la ligne 12, des rames aux couleurs de Volkswagen](https://www.leparisien.fr/info-paris-ile-de-france-oise/transports/sur-la-ligne-12-des-rames-aux-couleurs-de-volkswagen-07-10-2016-6184233.php)

> je veux parler de représenter un drapeau sur un train, puis-je le faire avec livrée ?

Les exemples cités me fait répondre que non, **aux couleurs de** me semble plus conforme à l'usage européen.

Answer (score 0):

La livrée, utilisée non seulement pour les trains et les voitures mais aussi pour les avions et les personnels en uniforme, fait référence à la décoration générale des objets concernés ou à l'uniforme des personnes concernées.

Les couleurs sont plutôt synonymes de drapeau ("hissez les couleurs!"), de blason ou de logo (pour une entreprise), soit un signe d'appartenance ou de provenance plus discret que la livrée.